# Canon PowerShot A810 lens error

Tags: lens, canon, error, powershot

I have a Canon PowerShot A810. I don't know what happened to it, but when I turn it off, the lens doesn't close completely, starts buzzing, and after a few seconds, it says "Lens Error".

It extends completely fine (unless it isn't manually pushed in after turning off), so I'm confused.
I can cancel the lens error by pushing it in after it turns off.

If I try to zoom, it also does the lens error. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer here is the same as it is for any other fault on a 10 year old compact camera: it's not economically viable to fix. If you *particularly* like the A810, you can pick another one up on eBay relatively cheaply.

Comment: Yeah, I just found this in the garage, too. It makes sense.